# Goal of C's "auto" keyword

Tags: c++, c, c++11

What is the goal of the `auto` keyword in C? With C++ 0x it got new meaning but does it mean that my code will break if I port C code over to a C++ 0x compiler?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bjarne Stroustrup mentions in his [C++0x FAQ](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#auto) about `auto`:

> "The old meaning of auto ("this is a
>   local variable") is redundant and
>   unused. Several committee members
>   trawled through millions of lines of
>   code finding only a handful of uses --
>   and most of those were in test suites
>   or appeared to be bugs."

So I assume, that compilers wil not be forced by the standard to implement the old meaning of `auto`.

Answer (score 45):

It will break if your code contains the `auto` keyword. In nearly 30 years of C and C++  programming I've never come across any that did. The keyword was introduced in the first C compiler to specify local function variables, but compilers almost immediately became clever enough not to require it, and very little code that uses it will survive today - that's why C++0x chose to recycle it rather than introduce a new keyword which *would* cause portability problems.

The purpose of the auto keyword in C++0X is to allow the compiler to work out the type of a variable, where this is possible:

```
vector <int> v;
auto it = v.begin():
```

the compiler can see that v.begin() must return a `vector<int>::iterator` and so can create a variable of that type, saving a lot of keyboarding or typedef creation.

Comment: That's awesome, I hate typing out vector iterators ;)

Comment: Why will it break code that contains `auto`? Isn't the old meaning still valid?

Comment: @mottii To be honest, I'm not sure - a compiler can certainly see that `auto int i;` is not auto being used in the new sense, but I'm not sure if the standard requires them to do so.

Comment: @Motti: It will break any code that used `auto` in the old meaning, unless it was being used in a case where `int` was implicit. Think of `auto` as the type; is `int float` valid? Then neither is `auto float`, or `auto int`. However, the exception I stated above is that in classic C, `auto i = 0;` created an automatically allocated variable, who's type is implicitly `int`, named `i`, initialized to 0. This case will happen to work with the new meaning. (`auto` will deduced to be an `int`, because the type of the initializer, 0, is `int`.)

Comment: @Motti For what it's worth g++ in c++0x mode barfs on  auto int i;

Comment: @Neil & @GMan, I seem to remember that the new usage of the `auto` keyword should not break existing code but I can't find any reference to that. As far as compilers go, VS10 agrees with you and Comeau agrees with me (I usually trust Comeau more where standard compliance is involved but YMMV).

http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/

Comment: According to the C++03 standard, `auto` can be used to disambiguate "ambiguous" code for humans. As in the following code `auto int(n);` to tell the human that it's a variable declared and not a cast to `int`. But the compiler really doesn't need it :)

Comment: C++0X FCD, C.1.5: "7.1.6.4: Change: The keyword auto cannot be used as a storage class specifier." page 1205 of PDF N3092.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that the purpose of auto is not just to save typing out the type of the variable. It also prevents the cascading of compile errors when a small change is made. For example, if you change the type of a variable from std::map to std::unordered_map, ordinarily you would have to go through and change all the iterator types. With auto, you don't have to worry about this. It makes the programmer more efficient.

Answer (score 10):

In C, `auto` specified automatic storage duration (as opposed to `static`, `extern`, `register`). Since this is the default, I have never seen `auto` used in any code. I haven't done much C, though.

Answer (score 5):

This answer **is wrong**, see [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847734/is-auto-int-i-valid-c0x), I'm leaving the answer here as a reference.

---

<strike>AFAIK C++0x's use of `auto` doesn't contradict C traditional usage of `auto`. In C `auto` is used together with the type.</strike>

```
auto char c1 = 'a'; // OK, old meaning of auto is still valid
auto c2 = 'b'; // OK, new meaning of auto (deduce c2 is a char)
```

The only place where it can change the meaning of the code is when auto was used together with the *implicit `int`* rule (if not type is specified -> it's an `int`) in which case the second line in my example used to have `c2` of type `int` and now it's of type `char`.

Comment: Doesn't compile with g++, FWIW.

Comment: Thanks @Neil, I asked a new question to find out who's right (I can't find anything the C++0x draft)

Comment: I surprised they didn't allow for this given all of the other warts in C++ for the sake of C compatibility. ;)

Answer (score 3):

It is rarely used; it meant a local variable. Modern compilers such as VS2010 C++ give it a [new meaning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k3ybftz.aspx).

Comment: This new meaning is from the C++0x standard as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated answer to an old question:

As far as I can tell from 40+ years of C programming, including compiler work, the `auto` keyword has been completely useless in C for 50 years.  You are unlikely to have used this keyword in your C code, so no portability issue should arise from this semantic change (but many other semantic changes can cause portability problems).

Note however that recent advances in the proposed C23 Standard give `auto` updated semantics in C, modelled after C++.

`auto` seems to be a left over from [B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_(programming_language)), the predecessor to the C language, developed by Ken Thompson and Dennis Ritchie at Bell Labs in the late sixties and early seventies.

Before C23, `auto` can only be used to specify automatic storage class for definitions in the scope of a function. This is the default, so `auto` is fully redundant and as long as the type or another qualifier is specified, `auto` can be removed. There isn't any case where it was needed, so its inclusion in the C Standard is only rooted in the early history of the C language.

`auto` has been used in C++ since C++11 to enable type inference in variable definitions, with or without automatic storage, where the compiler detects the type from that of the initializer.

With the current trend pushing for convergence on a common subset for the C and C++ languages, new semantics have been attached to this keyword in C23 modelled after the C++ semantics, but more restricted:

> **6.7.1 Storage-class specifiers**
>
> `auto` may appear with all the others except `typedef`;
>
> `auto` shall only appear in the declaration specifiers of an identifier with file scope or along with other storage class specifiers if the type is to be inferred from an initializer.
>
> If `auto` appears with another storage-class specifier, or if it appears in a declaration at file scope, it is ignored for the purposes of determining a storage duration of linkage. It then only indicates that the declared type may be inferred.

Type inference is specified as:

> **6.7.9 Type inference**
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 1 A declaration for which the type is inferred shall contain the storage-class specifier `auto`.
>
> **Description**
>
> 2 For such a declaration that is the definition of an object the init-declarator shall have one of the forms
>
> *direct-declarator = assignment-expression*
> *direct-declarator = { assignment-expression }*
> *direct-declarator = { assignment-expression , }*
>
> The declared type is the type of the assignment expression after lvalue, array to pointer or function to pointer conversion, additionally qualified by qualifiers and amended by attributes as they appear in the declaration specifiers, if any. If the direct declarator is not of the form *identifier attribute-specifier-sequence<sub>opt</sub>*, possibly enclosed in balanced pairs of parentheses, the behavior is undefined.

Type inference is very useful in C++ because types can be very complex and almost impossible to specify in variable definitions, especially with templates. Conversely, using it in C is probably counter productive, lessening code readability and encouraging laziness and error prone practices.  It was already bad enough to hide pointers behind typedefs, now you can hide them completely with the `auto` keyword.

---

To finish on a less serious note, I remember seeing it used in tricky interview tests, where the candidate is asked to find why this code does not compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char word[80];
    int auto = 0;
    while (scanf("%79s", word) == 1) {
        if (!strcmp(word, "car")
        ||  !strcmp(word, "auto")
        ||  !strcmp(word, "automobile"))
            auto++;
    }
    printf("cars: %d\n", auto);
    return 0;
}
```