# Is "auto int i" valid C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, standards-compliance

In answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847410/goal-of-cs-auto-keyword/2847490#2847490) the question arose as to whether the traditional **C** meaning of the keyword `auto` (automatic, rather than `static` or `extern` storage) is still valid in **C++11** now that it means type deduction.

I remember that the old meaning of `auto` should remain where relevant but others disagreed.

```
auto char c = 42; // either compilation error or c = '*'
```

Looking at compilers I see the current division.

1. Old meaning of auto is no longer allowed

- VS10
- g++

2. Old meaning of auto is used where relevant

- [Comeau](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/)

Do you know which is the correct behaviour?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, it is not. In fact, §7.1.6.​4/3 gives the following example:

```
auto x = 5; // OK: x has type int
const auto *v = &x, u = 6; // OK: v has type const int*, u has type const int
static auto y = 0.0; // OK: y has type double
auto int r; // error: auto is not a storage-class-specifier
```

As you can see, it results in an error. §7.1.6.​5 pretty much seals the deal with:

> A program that uses auto in a context not explicitly allowed in this section is ill-formed.

Comment: +1 for telling me something I didn't know. -1 to C++1x committee, for another useless breakage of compatibility with C.

Comment: @Pavel: I'd hardly call it useless or breaking. How often do you find `auto` being used *at all* in current day C or C++ code?

Comment: I see you've initialized 2 auto variables there, I assume it works kinda like a typedef ie. you can't do: `auto x = 5, y = 5.0f;`
Will be great for defining begin and end iterators though

Comment: GMan: 1. It is definitely breaking of a language, regardless of how many programs it breaks. 2. It is useless, because the same goal could have been achieved without [1]: just retain the functionality of auto as a storage class if type is explicitly specified.

Comment: It breaks no real programs, and it makes the language simpler to understand. The old meaning for auto was useless.

Comment: In fact, any program broken deserves to be broken. The old usage was worse than useless; it was misleading.

Comment: @Pavel: I will accept that theoretically it is a breaking update (because there is, after all, a way to write proper C++03 code that breaks with this change.) but I think you're completely misguided in disagreeing with the change. There should literally be no modern code that uses `auto`, since it's superfluous. Might as well make something useful out of it. Also, your compatibility seems to be with C, which is meaningless and irrelevant. C++ is not C, who cares what doesn't match. Do you complain about templates because they break C compatibility?

Comment: GMan, I don't get it. To break something, even unimportant, one needs at least a tiny wee reason. Such was not supplied. They could introduce this syntax without breaking anything.

Comment: @Pavel: Is "old auto isn't used" not reason enough? No C++ code used `auto`. It literally could be stripped from the language and 99% of code (100% of good code) would work unchanged. Introducing new keywords is far worse then reusing an old used one. I really don't see your complaint. Nothing is broken. If your code breaks from this change, you were writing shitty code, period.

Comment: @GMan I didn't ask for a new keyword. They could use the very same keyword for the new functionality, and still not break anything - easily.