# C++ or C++0x - Which is a better standard?

Tags: c++, c++11

So I've been trying to do some research and would like the opinions of other developers on this topic. I am an experienced C++ programmer and have been using the current C++ standard for some time. I have been reading articles that "C++0x will undoubtedly become the new standard." How far off are we does everyone think from making the switch to a whole new programming standard? Also, which, in your eyes, is a better standard? From how I understand it, C++0x will come with more standard libraries making development easier without many more dependencies. Please help me to catch up!

Thanks!
Dennis M.

Comment: Actually, they're both on par for reading (dry and witless). But, when contemplating how best to kill someone on SO for asking inane questions, the C++0x standard is a clear winner. It's much thicker and will crush skulls in half the time taken by the current standard :-)

Comment: Neither 'C++' nor 'C++0x' are a standard. The latest C++ language spec is C++03. 'C++0x' is the moniker used for the latest language spec *draft*. Herb Sutter has indicated that he expects the latest draft will likely be approved as 'C++11`, meaning approved in 2011, or at latest, if changes are needed, in 2012, meaning the draft would become 'C++12'.

Comment: @paxdiablo, you can't say the spec is *entirely* dry and witless. There are easter eggs. For instance, footnote on page 1107 of the FCD: "341) Atomic objects are neither active nor radioactive." And yes, I actually did find it on my own by reading through the tomb.

Comment: @Nathan, wow, I'm impressed. I've only ever used the standard to look up specific issues, not read it cover to cover like a Grisham book :-) I had a hard time believing that, but there it is, right at the bottom of the page in the n3092 draft. I can't believe they'll leave that in, that would be almost unheard of. I'd like to apologise to the members of WG21. Obviously, _they're_ not witless. And I think you may have meant tome, although tomb is funnier, "place for the dead".

Comment: @pax: It has indeed been removed. :(

Comment: @paxdiablo:  I dunno; if the limerick about template specialization leading to self immolation could get into C++98 (14.7.3/7), I wouldn't count out other jokes getting in.  Several C++0x drafts had redefined "ill-formed program" in the definitions at the beginning to mean "a wannabe C++ program."  I think that one's been removed though, too.

Comment: @James: If I had to guess, they change the jokes in each draft.

Comment: @paxdiablo, you're correct, it should have been tome, and not tomb. But, I was drunk and tired last night when I wrote that. I haven't read the standard (or any draft) cover-to-cover, but I have read through sections that are of particular interest to me, in this case, the new atomics library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would be pretty sad if the next version of C++ were quantitatively worse than the current one. The entire point of the new revision is to improve things.

Comment: Naturally. But I read something about "Boost" being similar to a C++0x; is that statement far off? I feel boostlib is very good for somethings, but I am not a huge fan of it myself. Sorry for such a seemingly asinine question, I'm trying to simply perceive a better concept of where things are moving.

Comment: @Dennis: Boost is an unofficial "de facto" standard library for C++ that is intended to provide libraries that work well with the C++ standard library. It is intended that libraries in Boost are that are broadly useful will eventually get standard (as has happened with things like `shared_ptr<T>` already). Read all about it at http://www.boost.org/

Comment: @Ken, true.  But @Dennis, of course, like any part of the standard library, it's your choice if and when to use it.  So, e.g. if you didn't use `boost::shared_ptr`, you don't have to suddenly start using `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Boost and C++0x are actually pretty closely related -- a lot of the same people are working on both.

Answer (score 7):

Well, it depends.

The current C++ standard (C++03) is *currently* "better" because most of the latest C++ compilers and standard library implementations conform fairly well to the standard.  Yes, there are issues, but most of them are very well known (e.g., hardly any compiler supports export) or are fairly easy to work around.

Support for C++0x is pretty patchy right now.  Different compilers support different parts and there have been pretty major modifications made to it over the last year, so compilers that did provide early support for some features are now "buggy" if you consider their conformance to the latest drafts.

Going forward, though, C++0x will be a huge improvement over C++03.  Major features like the concurrency memory model and the standard threads and atomics libraries are extremely important for the future of the language.  Move semantics will make it easier to write clean, high performance code.  Most of the new language features will make developing in C++ a more enjoyable experience.

Answer (score 2):

"C++0x will undoubtedly become the new standard" is an understatement. C++0x is the draft of the new standard. Parts of it are available now in compilers like G++ 4.5.

It is **impossible** for C++0x to be qualitatively worse than the current C++ standard, because one of the essential things about the new standard is that it is **fully backward compatible**. If there are bad parts, you can just avoid them. (Of course, that doesn't mean that new features in C++0x can't be used to create really bad code that you'll have to deal with, but if you're coding on your own, you can always choose to avoid C++0x features that are worse in your opinion.)

Comment: "One of the essential things about the new standard is that it is fully backward compatible" - it's a very strong claim that's provably incorrect. For example, the following valid C++03 program: `int static_assert = 0;` - is not a valid C++0x program. It's a trivial case, but numerous other subtle differences are there. It is definitely _highly_ backwards compatible, though.

Comment: You're exaggerating a bit.  It's not *completely* backwards compatible.  E.g. [unusual uses of auto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847734/is-auto-int-i-valid-c0x) will break.  Moreover, if languages grow too big, they can become unmanageable, and thus "worse".  I don't think C++ has hit that point, but it's certainly a general possibility.

Comment: I just _love_ people who use the "impossible" word. People who think later versions cannot be worse haven't met my friend, Guido's, third wife :-)

Comment: @dan04, I said that, didn't I.

Comment: @paxdiablo: That's because Guido's third wife wasn't built for complete backwards compatibility with his second wife.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by "better". If you mean "More likely to work with whichever compiler I'm using at the moment", then the old standard will certainly be better, with a little [boost](http://www.boost.org/) thrown in.