# c++ Error 3 error C2159: more than one storage class specified

Tags: c++

I use Visual Studio 2008 to compile my source and it just keeps giving me this error:

```
c++ Error   3   error C2159: more than one storage class specified
```

I spent sleepless nights on it and couldn't figure out where the problem is.

C++ code

```
    #pragma once

#define SET_EXCEPTION(x) PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, #x)

bool PyTuple_GetString(PyObject* poArgs, int pos, char** ret);
bool PyTuple_GetInteger(PyObject* poArgs, int pos, unsigned char* ret);
bool PyTuple_GetInteger(PyObject* poArgs, int pos, int* ret);
bool PyTuple_GetInteger(PyObject* poArgs, int pos, WORD* ret);
bool PyTuple_GetByte(PyObject* poArgs, int pos, unsigned char* ret);
bool PyTuple_GetUnsignedInteger(PyObject* poArgs, int pos, unsigned int* ret);
bool PyTuple_GetLong(PyObject* poArgs, int pos, long* ret);
bool PyTuple_GetUnsignedLong(PyObject* poArgs, int pos, unsigned long* ret);
bool PyTuple_GetFloat(PyObject* poArgs, int pos, float* ret);
bool PyTuple_GetDouble(PyObject* poArgs, int pos, double* ret);
bool PyTuple_GetObject(PyObject* poArgs, int pos, PyObject** ret);
bool PyTuple_GetBoolean(PyObject* poArgs, int pos, bool* ret);

bool PyCallClassMemberFunc(PyObject* poClass, const char* c_szFunc, PyObject* poArgs);
bool PyCallClassMemberFunc(PyObject* poClass, const char* c_szFunc, PyObject* poArgs, bool* pisRet);
bool PyCallClassMemberFunc(PyObject* poClass, const char* c_szFunc, PyObject* poArgs, long * plRetValue);

bool PyCallClassMemberFunc_ByPyString(PyObject* poClass, PyObject* poFuncName, PyObject* poArgs);
bool PyCallClassMemberFunc(PyObject* poClass, PyObject* poFunc, PyObject* poArgs);

PyObject * Py_BuildException(const char * c_pszErr = NULL, ...);
PyObject * Py_BadArgument();
PyObject * Py_BuildNone();
PyObject * Py_BuildEmptyTuple();

static auto &&PyTuple_GetDWORD = PyTuple_GetUnsignedLong;
```

The compiler points that the error is in line 31, which is

```
static auto &&PyTuple_GetDWORD = PyTuple_GetUnsignedLong;
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think Visual Studio 2008 supports rvalue references or `auto`. You need VS2012 or later for C++11 features.

Comment: This source was compiled on VS2008 by other competitors in the same business as me. Please consider a look at the following lines from the project SLN:

Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
# Visual Studio 2008

Comment: According to this VS2010 had rvalue and auto support, but definitely not 2008: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: Bump to @JonathanPotter 's comment. I cried when I had to roll-back the changes I started making to some VS2010 projects when I was told they had to be source-VS2008 compliant for back patches. I had to put `auto` back on the shelf until the neanderthals decide its finally time to come out of the iron ages.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll upgrade to Visual Studio 2010 and see what will happen. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword `auto` had a different meaning prior to C++11. It meant a variable is an automatic variable, its scope is local. In C++11, its meaning changed to mean "deduce the type" of the variable.

Since VS 2008 does not support C++11 constructs, it interprets the `auto` with its old meaning. When interpreted like that,

```
static auto &&PyTuple_GetDWORD = PyTuple_GetUnsignedLong;
```

does not make sense since a variable can't be `static` and `auto` at the same time.

Related post: [Goal of C's "auto" keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847410/goal-of-cs-auto-keyword)

Comment: So that means I have to upgrade to Visual Studio 2010 in order for the source to work as expected?

Comment: @D3XT3R, I don't think VS 2010 will supports c++11. You'll have to jump to VS 2012. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.